# Deeplink prettyphoto

Tags: jquery, share, prettyphoto

On my website I open some WP-Pages into a iframe via link.

```
<a href="http://www.xxx/?p=130?iframe=true&amp;width=100%&amp;height=100%" rel="prettyPhoto[iframes]" onclick="white()"><font class="featured-text">Andreas Till</font><br>Visual Haiku</a>
```

How can I share this link direct (deeplink) to open it direct in prettyphotos.